# NullPointerException when trying to change text of textview on click

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I am trying to change the text of a textView after a user clicks on an image (could have easily been a button). I keep getting a force close and nullpointerexception. I'm trying to write it for Android 2.3.3

The code is based off many examples found on google.

```
public class TestImagesActivity extends Activity { 
    private android.view.View.OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
            final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.svariable);
            txt.setText("new text"); // this line throws an exception
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    image.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
}
```

my main.XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android.id="@+id/svariable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/test_image"
   android:src="@drawable/test"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried adding anroid:onclick to the ImageView? Then just call that function instead of using a listener. Just as a test, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML you're using ***android.id*** instead of ***android:id*** for svariable.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small problem in the XML, this:

```
android.id="@+id/svariable"
```

Should be:

```
android:id="@+id/svariable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your XML `android.id` to `android:id`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `mCorkyListener` is created when the activity class is loaded, before the `onCreate` method is called. And as you may know, you can't inflate any views before you call `setContentView(layout)`, where `layout` is the parent view of your views. So your `TextView` inside the listener creation code will always be null. You should create the listener after the `setContentView` call. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think (but am not certain) that it would work the way he has it. Because onClick() won't be getting called until after setContentView gets called from onCreate. I don't believe it will try to evaluate what is inside the onClick() until the image is actually pressed.

Comment: Yes but it's a pointless way of implementing a listener - just as easy to have the `Activity` implement the listener itself and then set the listener using `this`. Also more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is also worth noting that findViewById() is a fairly expensive method call in terms of device resources.

You should get your TextView reference from this call inside your onCreate method next the same call that you use to get your imageView reference. That way it doesn't get called each time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a typo.

`android.id="@+id/svariable"` should be 
`android:id="@+id/svariable"`